# How is .NET Core isolated storage "secured" on various OS's?

Tags: tpm, bitlocker, secure-coding, asp.net-core, icloud

I'm looking for a consolidated list of how and where [isolated storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage) is managed on each operating system... (Windows, MacOS, Linux, (mobile?), ...)

Does such a list exist?

What considerations might be worth considering in conjunction or as an alternative? (e.g. TPM integration, SecureElement, or for cloud scenarios KeyVault, iCloud Keychain, ...more)

The result of this research could result in a NugetLibrary that assists .NET Core developers to leverage current and future platform features for private keys, or other security sensitive material.

Inspecting an API call says that the following are supported for Isolated Storage:

[image]

Comment: I would guess that isolated storage does not work in anything but Windows without some manual intervention. (forking for OS) I'd think that any benefit you get from using this storage in the first place would be access to Windows-specific domain security.

Comment: @pcalkins just updated with OS support that indicates other platforms are supported somehow

Comment: ahh, I see, so you can probably find the paths regarding mono/Xamarin then.   Maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026335/how-to-get-all-available-storages-paths-in-xamarin-forms